# Matlab - Symmetric PSD of an Image using fft

Tags: image, matlab, fft, psd

I wanted to have one dimensional PSD for an Image calculated (along rows and columns separately) using matlab.

I use the following snippet for the same.

```
F=fft(img,[],2);%FFT along dim2
F=fftshift(F,2);
mtf=(abs(F)).^2;
mtf_mean = mean(mtf,2);% Mean of all contents of a row
mtf_mean_norm = mtf_mean/max(max(mtf_mean)); %Normalization to 1
plot(mtf_mean_norm);
```

When I plot it, I expected a symmetrical plot with respect to a center (and that's what I want). But, I happen to see that two parts look asymmerical like in the attached figure.

Looks like I have a code bug, Any clues what am I missing ?

Image url: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RrLIt.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I am not an image processing person, but just from my own stats knowledge I would say.
you should use `mtf=abs(F)'*abs(F)` instead of `mtf=(abs(F)).^2`. I got the following figure
[image]

here is the code that generates the figure.

```
> img=randn(50,50);
> F=fft(img,[],2);%FFT along dim2
> F=fftshift(F,2);
> mtf=abs(F)'*abs(F);
> mtf_mean = mean(mtf,2);% Mean of all contents of a row
> mtf_mean_norm = mtf_mean/max(max(mtf_mean)); %Normalization to 1
> plot(mtf_mean_norm);
> plot(mtf_mean_norm);
```